# Can JMS resources be targeted to multiple managed servers in weblogic?

Tags: queue, jms, weblogic

I have following kind of a scenario:

```
I have two managed servers -> Managed_BridgeServer & Managed_ApplicationServer ,
3 JMS resources -> Requestqueue , Responsequeue , ConnFac
1 Subdeployment -> JMSSubDep 
1 JMS Server -> JMSServer1
```

Targeting is as follows:

```
JMS resources -> JMSSubDep -> JMSServer1 -> Managed_BridgeServer
```

There's a Bridge that's hosted on this server for which Destination is my Requestqueue and Source is an another queue hosted on different application.

On my Managed_ApplicationServer, there's an MDB that listens to the Requestqueue ( mentioned above )
However , the MDB is not able to pick up the message from the queue as it's not able to recognise the queue since its JNDI is not registered with this Managed_ApplicationServer. ( Note: requestqueue is targeted to Managed_BridgeServer )

My requirement is, that I should be able to target my JMS resources to both these managed servers so that my bridge and application both can access them and function properly.

Is there a way I can implement this? I tried exploring uniform distributed queues as an option but I am not sure if that's the perfect choice here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do so. You can have 2 JMS servers, each having their own persistence store and 1 JMS module which is targeted to the Managed servers. Of course this can only be done if the managed servers are clustered so if you set up a cluster, the Uniform Queues and Topics can be shared across them.